# Agregar varias líneas en un ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo que graficar las temperaturas (maxima, minima y media promedio) durante el año. Quisiera presentar un gráfico de líneas con las tres variables, pero no logro hacerlo.
print(clima)

```
        Meses Lluvia.mm. T_max T_min T_med
1       Enero       65.2  30.6     6  23.2
2     Febrero       62.4  29.4     5  22.2
3       Marzo       85.2  26.2     3  19.6
4       Abril       59.7  21.5    12  15.3
5        Mayo       39.9  17.6     1  11.8
6       Junio       35.6  13.7     8   8.5
7       Julio       28.2  13.6     7   8.2
8      Agosto       28.3  16.1     9   9.9
9  Septiembre       45.6  18.4    10  11.9
10    Octubre       64.5  21.5    11  14.8
11  Noviembre       60.0  25.6     2  18.4
12  Diciembre       71.1  28.8     4  21.5
```

Hice los gráficos por separado, pero quisiera que estén las tres variables en uno. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Para poder personalizar un gráfico como el que quieres hacer, te aconsejo que utilices la librería `ggplot2`. No es sencillo al principio, pero según vayas aprendiendo verás las posibilidades que te proporciona.

En tu caso, podría ser útil el siguiente ejemplo:

```
# Poner como factor los meses (para que el orden sea el cronológico y no el alfabético)
  df$Meses <- factor(df$Meses, levels = c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo",
                                          "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", 
                                          "Noviembre", "Diciembre"))

 
# Agupar los valores a representar en un objeto "melt" [esto facilita la representación]
  df2 <- melt(df[,c("Meses", "T_max", "T_min")])
  
  
# Realizar el gráfico  
  P1 <- ggplot(data = df2, 
               aes(x = Meses, y = value, group = variable, colour = variable)) +
    # Representar las líneas
      geom_line(size=1.5) +
    # Representar los puntos [en función de "variable", es decir T_max o T_min]
      geom_point(size=4, aes(shape=variable)) +
    # Determinar las figuras deseadas para los puntos (cuadrados y círculos)
      scale_shape_manual(values = c(15,16)) +
    # Fondo blanco
      theme_bw() +

    # Colores de las líneas para los grupos
      scale_color_manual(values = c("red","blue")) 

# Para visualizar el resultado . . .
  P1
```

Para comenzar creo que puede servirte, aunque insisto en que `ggplot2` te permite personalizar mucho más el gráfico.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!